# Unable to set user credential using Keycloak admin api

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

We are importing users to KeyCloak using Java code, and we are using `keycloak-admin-client` API.

Tried Setting password as follows , but it is not setting/persisting the password for the user.

```
 CredentialRepresentation credential = new CredentialRepresentation();
    credential.setType(CredentialRepresentation.PASSWORD);
    credential.setValue("password");
    userRepresentation.setCredentials(Arrays.asList(credential));
```

Is there other way to set user credentials

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used following Endpoint to set the Credentials

```
UserResource userResource = keycloak.realm(realm).users().get(userId);
CredentialRepresentation credential = new CredentialRepresentation();
    credential.setType(CredentialRepresentation.PASSWORD);
    credential.setValue(password);
    credential.setTemporary(false);
    userResource.resetPassword(credential);
```

Comment: An obvious doubt...why can't we use userRepresentation.setCredentials() method to set the password?